# How to determine when UITableView is done loading all the rows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to determine when the UITableView is done loading all the rows?

I am not sure if this is causing a problem for me but. I try to auto-select the first row in the table and it doesn't do it and there is at least one row.

Comment: If you're using selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:, make sure you're calling it in your viewController's viewDidLoad method, or afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reloadData` is a synchronous call. So as soon as `reloadData` returns, the table view will have loaded all visible cells.

Comment: So does this means all the drawing of the visible rows  and cell are done as well?  I am trying to select a row after a call to [tableview reloadData] but the cell/row is never hightlighted. I had to use a NSTimer to wait a few secs to get it to work. Sounds like a bad work-around

Comment: This isn't quite what I experience. Specifically, I find that the various height method (e.g. `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) are called before I `reloadData` returns, but other methods, such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are not called until after `reloadData` returns.

Comment: `reloadData` used to be synchronous, but it's not anymore. Some methods like `cellForRow...` are called asynchronously now.